# Google Sheets - sorting after arrayformula

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, array-formulas

I am a total newb...so please be patient.

I have a google sheet where I am pulling data from one sheet (Squarespace Data) to a master sheet (Test Master).  I am using array formula because the information on Squarespace Data will be auto-filled from my website with automate.io as new orders are placed.

There are multiple columns on Squarespace Data but the one in question is SKU which I use regex extract on Squarespace Data to split into "Class Date" and "Class Title" columns

Here are the formulas (B1 and C1 are just the text for the regular expression):

```
={"CLASS DATE";iferror(arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT('Squarespace Data'!B3:B,$B$1)),"")}

={"CLASS TITLE";iferror(arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT('Squarespace Data'!B3:B,$C$1)),"")}
```

I want to sort ALL OF THE DATA by date, and then by class.  It should effectively group the orders from the website by the actual class that will be taught (unique identifier is Class Date + Class Title...but several different students could buy the same class).

Here is a link to the sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UBWVbxObW3MJ9d1Qo2ZNObvMhJ4w6P8qXA7DrYX8yuI/edit?usp=sharing

The tab "Squarespace Data" is autofilled.
The tab "Test Master" is where I am working on all of the formulas
The tab "MASTER" is the desired look when done (right now all hard coded)
the rest of the tabs are for future

Any pointers?

Comment: Welcome. So... what is the question. How to sort, how to share, how to group...? Please read [ask] so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: on top right in your sheet there is a share button... set share to View or Edit... paste the url here... include some example of desired result

Comment: Edited....added link and explanation of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

First you join the columns and then you split them again. After that you can sort them by the index of the column.

```
=SORT(
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        IFERROR(SPLIT(
            ARRAYFORMULA(
                FILTER('raw data'!A1:A; NOT(ISBLANK('raw data'!A1:A))) 
                    & "°" 
                    & 'raw data'!B1:B)
        ;"°");"")
    )
;1;TRUE)
```

Example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sGTG6lofwHJBqcIrlvARaqoPH-yLAh5jMlFDshpN7LI/edit?usp=sharing